# Java 8 : Without using if else

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm learning Java 8, Is any way to convert `if else` statement much simpler?

use if-else logic in Java 8 optional flatmap

**ex:**

```
    if (!ifStmtStack.isEmpty()) {
        ifStmt = (IfStatement) ifStmtStack.pop();
    }
```

Comment: How about : ifStmt = ifStmtStack.isEmpty() ?  null : (IfStatement) ifStmtStack.pop();

Comment: What could possibly be "much simpler" than `if`? It's as simple as it can get.